# Почему js код в Яндекс Браузере работает только при открытой консоли?

Tags: javascript, кроссбраузерность

Сам проект еще не доделан, но встретилась такая ошибка:
Планируется сделать так, что после того, как пользователь вводит данные в любые 3 тега input, все остальные теги input блокируются. Сам код я тестировал в яндекс Браузере, но там он почему-то правильно выполняется только при открытой консоли разработчика. Я проверял этот же код в Google Chrome, там все работает исправно.Кто знает, с чем может быть связана проблема?

ссылка на проект: https://spleekz.github.io/triangle/

Answer (score 2):

проверил на хроме работает как запрограммировано. У вас на каждом изменении увеличивается i++. то есть если менять 3 раза одно и тоже поле то вы получите блокировку всех остальных, и браузер тут не причем.

Советую смотреть на значения всех ваших переменных если не можете считать количество введенных.

Comment: да, про эту проблему я знаю,так как не все еще успел доделать. Я только не понимаю, почему в Яндекс Браузере код правильно работает, только при условии что открыта консоль.Я уже проверил в хроме и в фаерфоксе, там все работает и без открытой консоли

Comment: Я не понимаю того что значит работает правильно не верно. Проверил на яндексе такое же поведение после 3 изменений получаю блокировку

Comment: и плевать что открыта или нет консоль разраба